# Load GeoJson using an object instead of an url in Here Maps

Tags: javascript, geojson, here-api, heremaps

I'm trying to use GeoJson in Here Maps. I'm new to Here Maps API, so I'm following the official example to load a GeoJson and everything works fine if I load the GeoJson from an url. Now I want to load the GeoJson from a JS Object, but the `geojson.Reader` method seems that only allows to read an url. Is it possible to load an Object?

```
var myGeoJsonObject = ...

function showGeoJSONData (map) {

var reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader(myGeoJsonObject), {

    style: function (mapObject) {

      if (mapObject instanceof H.map.Polygon) {
        mapObject.setStyle({
          fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
          lineWidth: 3
        });
      }
    }
  });

  reader.parse();

  map.addLayer(reader.getLayer());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://developer.here.com/cn/documentation/maps/hls-chn/topics_api/h-data-geojson-reader.html), it seems that you have two options:

1. Pass a filepath to the constructor:

```
const reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader('/path/to/geojson/file.json');
reader.parse();
```

2. Or, you can create a new instance and pass nothing to the constructor. You can then call the `.parse` method on the instance and pass your GeoJSON object. You can still pass an options object to the constructor:

```
const reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader(null, {
    style: function (mapObject) {
      if (mapObject instanceof H.map.Polygon) {
        mapObject.setStyle({
          fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
          lineWidth: 3
        });
      }
    }
  });

// pass the data here
reader.parse(myGeoJsonObject);
```

Comment: Hi @LMulvey, thanks for your answer but it doesn't work either. It assumes that the object is an url.

Comment: Try this: `H.data.geojson.Reader(null, { //settings });`

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, but it also does not work.

Comment: Sigh (sighing at the API design, not you). The docs aren't really intuitive and it's not open source. Try this: `H.data.geojson.Reader(undefined, { //settings });`

Comment: It does not throw any error but does not work either. Thanks for your help LMulvey! Maybe it's time to try another alternative.

Comment: use `reader.parseData(myGeoJsonObject)` instead. 
See https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.22.0/api_reference/H.data.geojson.Reader.html#parseData

Comment: reader.parseData(myGeoJsonObject) not working, I get error : common_share.js:285 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'geojson')

Answer (score 1):

This is my working example:

```
                _current_geojson_layer = new H.data.geojson.Reader();
                // pass the data here
                _current_geojson_layer.parseData(_geojson_object);
                // Add layer which shows GeoJSON data on the map
                map.addLayer(_current_geojson_layer.getLayer());
```

Here is api doc

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.22.0/api_reference/H.data.geojson.Reader.html#parseData

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is required to use parseData, H.data.geojson.Reader.parseData: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.22.0/api_reference/H.data.geojson.Reader.html#parseData

```
    const reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader(null, {
    style: function (mapObject) {
      if (mapObject instanceof H.map.Polygon) {
        mapObject.setStyle({
          fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
          strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
          lineWidth: 3
        });
      }
    }
 });
// pass the data here
reader.parseData(myGeoJsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I resolved it by making sure i  imported

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-data.js"></script>
```

Then I could parse the GeoJson object by

```
    const reader = new H.data.geojson.Reader(undefined);
    reader.parseData(geojson_object);
    map.addLayer(reader.getLayer());
```

Hope this helps someone in future!